# Editing on high resolution image taking huge time to generate output image

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage, cifilter, imagefilter

I have been working on a photo editor app for iOS using cifilter framework and GPU image framework, it takes a lot of time when applying filters on high-resolution images.

In order to decrease the processing time, I implemented the **filtering** as well as **editing** feature by reducing the original size of them. Thus, as obvious, it produces a low-resolution image as an output.

Now I am struggling to generate high-resolution image in the output. Therefore, it would be a great help for me if anyone helps me by providing ideas or probable solutions to decrease the processing time or a way to upscale image resolution to the original resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In our apps, we use different resolutions for editing and exporting. For editing, the rendering needs to be fast and snappy, but for export, depending on the user-chosen export resolution, processing might take some time.

We reduce the export time for older devices by processing on a smaller resolution internally (but still much higher than preview resolution) and upsampling the image afterward.

For upsampling, you can use a joint bilinear upsampling technique, which uses the original image to scale up the smaller, filtered image with very high quality. Apple implemented this technique in the [`CIEdgePreserveUpsampleFilter`](https://cifilter.io/CIEdgePreserveUpsampleFilter/).

Comment: Thank you Frank. It helped me to upscale the image as the original image. But one more issue has occurred.  During edits, if I change the aspect ratio of the lower scaled image, suppose apply rotations or cropping and then try to export the final image with the joint bilinear upsampling technique then the output image becomes distorted as the ratio of the input image and the low scaled image is not same any more. So, how can I solve that issue? 
Once again thank you.

Comment: Yes, you would also need to apply those cropping and rotation operations to the original image (but relative to its size) before using it as a guide in the upsampling filter. Except for the size, the small image and the guide need to match in content, if that makes sense.